# Push the element into new associative array of objects

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I am not sure what's wrong with pushing the new element to associative array of objects

```
var storeData3 = [  
{ 'key1' : 'value1' },  
{ 'key2' : 'value2' },  
{ 'key3' : 'value3' },  
{ 'key6' : null},  
{ 'key7' : ''},  
{ 'key8' : ""},  
{ 'key9' : null},  
{ 'key10' : 'value4'}
]; //as JSON object

var i=0;

storeData3=JSON.stringify(storeData3, function(key, value)
{if(!value)
{
    i++;

};

return value;
});

JSON.parse(storeData3);

function insert(name, number) 
{
    storeData3.push({name: number});        
}

if(i>0) insert('keyX','null');
```

The errors says "TypeError: storeData3.push is not a function".

Comment: When you do `storeData3=JSON.stringify(storeData3, function(key, value)` `storeData3` becomes a string.

Comment: Because there is no storeData3.push() function

Comment: `JSON.parse(storeData3);` returns the parsed value, but you aren't doing anything with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `push` method on `storeData3` which is a string.

The line

```
storeData3=JSON.stringify(storeData3, function(key, value) ...
```

overwrites the variable with string JSON representation.

You have to do

```
storeData3 = JSON.parse(storeData3);
```

or use another variable.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to store the parsed JSON back into `storeData3`

```
JSON.parse(storeData3);
```

should be

```
storeData3 = JSON.parse(storeData3);
```

Comment: @Atle, it does; `.stringify` returns a String, `JSON.parse` returns the actualy structure, i.e. an Array. You can't `.push` into a String.

Comment: I know, but I just don't think the error message explains much before after you see what's wrong. "storeData3 has no method 'push'" would explain more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the JSON.parse function back into the array `storeData = JSON.parse(storeData3);`